# getDefaultSharedPreferences and MODE_MULTI_PROCESS

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is there any way of setting the mode of the preferences retrieved by `getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)` to `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` so it can be used across multiple processes?

If not, can the preferences file name used by `getDefaultSharedPreferences` be retrieved and used again with `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` setting `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` ?

Finally if none if this is possible, what's the best way to copy the preferences previously defined with `getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context)` to a new preference file that can be used with `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
setSharedPreferencesMode(Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to use it. Can you help ?

Comment: No i mean eclipse can not find this method on PreferenceManger.

Comment: It isnt a static method. You can't do PreferenceManager.setSharedPreferencesMode(). You need to get an instance of the PreferenceManager and call it on that. Maybe just post some code so we can see how you are trying to use the PreferenceManager

Comment: Also, what API level are you using (ie: what Android version are you targeting)?

Comment: trying to do PreferenceManager mymanager= new PreferenceManager...
i get The constructor PreferenceManager() is not visible

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12919/discussion-between-david-wasser-and-mak)

Comment: Normally you get a `PreferenceManager` using `getPreferenceManager()` if you are in a `PreferenceActivity`. Are you coding a `PreferenceActivity`? If not, you probably just want to use `getSharedPreferences()` from your Activity. That's why I suggsted that you post some code so that we know what you are trying to do. You can edit your original post and add relevant code. Otherwise it is difficult to help.

Comment: +1 for the replies in comments, you can copy all of them and put in your answer,that would be great for others.