# SharedPreference with MODE_MULTI_PROCESS issue

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

My app has an activity and a service.  When I first wrote it I learned to use sharedPreferences from the commonsware book using MODE_PRIVATE.  The app has grown, and for reasons beyond the scope of this post, I now need to run my service in a different process.

I found I can do this by specifying a name starting with a colon in the android:process statement in my manifest file.

However now my activity and my service are no longer reading the same sharedPreferences.  Researching this problem I see many reccommendations to use MODE_MULTI_PROCESS.  But I cannot figure out how to spedify it.

```
SharedPreferences myMemory = getSharedPreferences("myMemory", MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

This does not work because Eclipse can't find MODE_MULTI_PROCESS like it can find MODE_PRIVATE or MODE_WORLD_READABLE.

So, how can I specify MODE_MULTI_PROCESS ??
thanks, Gary

Comment: Already answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159386/getdefaultsharedpreferences-and-mode-multi-process/11160430#11160430

Answer (score 0):

MODE_MULTI_PROCESS was added in API level 11. If it's not showing up, most likely you are targeting an older version.

You will either need to change the version of Android you are targeting in your manifest, or use Build.VERSION.SDK_INT at runtime to detect the new platform. Multi-process is implied in earlier versions.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
   myMemory = context.getSharedPreferences("myMemory", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
} else {
   myMemory = context.getSharedPreferences("myMemory", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

See:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html